# Row Header in ListView In WPF

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

Can we show Row Header in ListView In WPF just like as spreadsheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just style the first column to look like a header and you are done.

Comment: can u tell me how can i style the first column as a row header?

Answer (score 3):

No there is no header in Listview. Use Datagrid insted of ListView.

Answer (score 1):

Use SimpleListAdapter to populate your list which will use a xml in background to populate the  arraylist of hashmaps and in that xml you can define header title and description of your own without digging in to complexity of custom adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Stack two ListViews on top of each other and bind the upper one to a string list of headers.